# Clojure Java Interop IllegalArgumentException No matching method found: id

Tags: java, clojure, interop

Original Java:

```
FilterFactory2 ff = CommonFactoryFinder.getFilterFactory2();
Filter idFilter = ff.id(ff.featureId("100"));
```

Clojure:

```clj
(let [^FilterFactory2 ff (CommonFactoryFinder/getFilterFactory2)
      ^Filter id-filter (.id ff (.featureId ff "100"))]
  (do something...))
```

When I run this I get `IllegalArgumentException No matching method found: id for class org.geotools.filter.FilterFactoryImpl  clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeMatchingMethod (Reflector.java:80)`

I know that means it is unable to find a method `id` for `ff`. I searched the [docs](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/javadocs/org/geotools/filter/FilterFactoryImpl.html) and there is an `Id` property. I reviewed the [Clojure Java Interop docs](http://clojure-doc.org/articles/language/interop.html#how-to-access-java-fields) and it says the dot notation `(.id ff)` should work for accessing Java properties. I am unsure how to change my code to get the proper result. I am good with Clojure but know very little about Java.

Re var length Java args:
To my understanding this question is not related to variable length Java arguments as the main fn `ff.id(ff.featureId("100"));` takes only one argument (`ff.featureId("100")`) which evaluates to a `String`.

Comment: @SamEstep what makes you say this involves variable length args? The fn `ff.id(ff.featureId("100"))` takes only one arg `ff.featureId("100")` which evaluates to a `String`. The issue I am having is with retrieving the `id` property from `ff`.

Comment: No, `ff.featureId("100")` evaluates to a [`FeatureId`](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/javadocs/org/opengis/filter/identity/FeatureId.html). Meanwhile, [`id`](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/javadocs/org/geotools/filter/FilterFactoryImpl.html#id(org.opengis.filter.identity.FeatureId...)) is a [varargs method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_syntax#Varargs), so from Clojure, you must pass it an array, as stated in the answer to the linked question.

Comment: I was confused by the FeatureId docs that say `"Features are identified as strings."` Additionally the Id doc(http://docs.geotools.org/stable/javadocs/org/opengis/filter/Id.html) is confusing to someone unfamiliar with Java and does not show anywhere that it is a varargs method. Regardless, even after changing the argument to an array I still get the same error. If I reformat it like the example in that link to `(ff/id (to-array '(.featureId ff identifier)))` I get `CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: No such namespace: ff`

Comment: The [`Id`](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/javadocs/org/opengis/filter/Id.html) class is not a varargs method; however, the [`FilterFactoryImpl#id`](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/javadocs/org/geotools/filter/FilterFactoryImpl.html#id(org.opengis.filter.identity.FeatureId...)) method, which you are trying to call, *is* a varargs method. You need to call it like this: `(.id ff (into-array [(.featureId ff "100")]))`

Comment: I was incorrectly using an alternative syntax suggested in the link you provided, thank you for your help and the explanation.